# Try to get to work Arducam IMX519 on Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi4

I have followed every step from the Arducam Gudie [Arducam Guide IMX519](https://www.arducam.com/downloads/arducam-imx519-start-guide.pdf). But I am getting the following message when I try to run libcamera-hello or libcamera-still -t 0:

libEGL warning: DRI2: failed to authenticate
Made X/EGL preview window
[0:05:54.878605558] [1851]  INFO Camera camera_manager.cpp:293 libcamera v0.0.0+3897-c3c878a9
[0:05:54.879023852] [1866] ERROR MediaDevice media_device.cpp:479 /dev/media0[]: Failed to open media device at /dev/media0: Permission denied
[0:05:54.879141481] [1866]  INFO DeviceEnumerator device_enumerator.cpp:218 Unable to populate media device /dev/media0 (Permission denied), skipping
[0:05:54.879220573] [1866] ERROR MediaDevice media_device.cpp:479 /dev/media3[]: Failed to open media device at /dev/media3: Permission denied
[0:05:54.879271443] [1866]  INFO DeviceEnumerator device_enumerator.cpp:218 Unable to populate media device /dev/media3 (Permission denied), skipping
[0:05:54.879336850] [1866] ERROR MediaDevice media_device.cpp:479 /dev/media1[]: Failed to open media device at /dev/media1: Permission denied
[0:05:54.879385479] [1866]  INFO DeviceEnumerator device_enumerator.cpp:218 Unable to populate media device /dev/media1 (Permission denied), skipping
[0:05:54.879447312] [1866] ERROR MediaDevice media_device.cpp:479 /dev/media2[]: Failed to open media device at /dev/media2: Permission denied
[0:05:54.879495515] [1866]  INFO DeviceEnumerator device_enumerator.cpp:218 Unable to populate media device /dev/media2 (Permission denied), skipping
ERROR: *** no cameras available ***

I flashed multiple times and reinstalled everything. Checked the cable several times. But I always get the same error.

Hope someone can help me out here.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I tried that guide too but have run into the same issue recently. Have you tried following this instruction from arducam forum to install the driver?

[Install_pivariety_pkgs.sh update and FAQ](https://forum.arducam.com/t/install-pivariety-pkgs-sh-update-and-faq/3060)

This resolved the **no cameras available error** and allowed me to run libcamera-still test successfully. I still cannot get libcamera-hello to work unfortunately.